# Change Prestashop database from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, utf-8, prestashop, utf8mb4

I would like to use some Unicode 6.0 special characters (like thumbs-up and thumbs-down) in my Prestashop database, I get an error

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'concat'

Will it work if I change the columns interclasation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci?
Will there be any other consequences by doing so, like error or malfunctioning of the store?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is between the `CHARACTER SETs` -- `utf8` vs `ut8mb4`.  It would be wise to switch to utf8mb4 throughout.  At the same time, switch to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for the collation.

What version of MySQL are you using?  There are potential complications with 5.5 and 5.6 that may require some workarounds.

Comment: I'm using version 5.6.37

Comment: If you run into a problem with an index limit of 767 bytes, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes